# List View inside relative layout and scroll view not covering screen

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have below layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/searchScreenBG">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/title_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_7sdp">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ib_hamburger"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_16sdp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_16sdp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ham_burger" />

            <com.rod.com.rod.ui.views.CTextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ib_hamburger"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/basic_details"
                android:textColor="@color/colorGreen" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/ib_back"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ib_hamburger"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_16sdp"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_16sdp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/left_arrow" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/reg_no_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title_bar"
            android:background="@color/colorWhite">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_reg_no"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorLightGrey" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/reg_no_layout"
            >
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/basic_details"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:background="@drawable/list_item_bg"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_10sdp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_district_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
                        android:text="@string/district"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_13sdp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_district"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_district_label"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_district_label"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_district_label"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorLightGrey" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_tehsil_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/tv_district"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
                        android:text="@string/tehsil"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_tehsil"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_district"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_tehsil_label"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_tehsil_label"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorLightGrey" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_date_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_district"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_district"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_district"
                        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                        android:text="@string/date"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_date"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_date_label"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_date_label"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_date_label"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorLightGrey" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_jild_no_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tv_date_label"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_tehsil"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_tehsil"
                        android:text="@string/jild_no"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_jild_no"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_jild_no_label"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_jild_no_label"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_jild_no_label"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorLightGrey" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_party_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_date"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_date"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_date"
                        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                        android:text="@string/party"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_party"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv_party_label"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tv_party_label"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_party_label"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorLightGrey" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/basic_details"
                    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/list_item_bg">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_member_details_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_40sdp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_40sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                        android:text="@string/member_details"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_16sdp" />

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/lv_members"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_member_details_label"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_40sdp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_40sdp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_40sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:divider="@color/colorLightGrey"
                        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/_1sdp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I want to make the relative layout below *basic_layout* cover the whole of the rest screen. How can I achieve that. After searching I had found that I should put a linear layout inside my scroll view, and then relative layouts should added. But that's of no help.
I want hierachy something like below:

```
----RelativeLayout
-------TitleBar
-------TextView
-------ScrollView (rest of screen)
----------RelativeLayout (upper portion of scroll view)
------------TextViews
----------RelativeLayout (rest of scrol view)
-------------TextView
-------------ListView
```

Any help please?

Comment: Why did you make everything a child of frame layout?

Comment: what type of layout you want to acheive exactly can you share a screen shot maybe ?

Comment: @AryanRaj coz i have to integrate a drawer as well

Comment: @Umair please check my edited question

Comment: @Naila ok now couple of questions. Why are you using drawer layout as parent layout and secondly you want to scroll listview and textviews in upper portion as well ?

Comment: @Umair I am adding it from some other activity (base activity). And I want to scroll the whole view inside scroll view tag, as well as list

Comment: @Naila ok now your problem is that the listview only shows one item or it's not matched parent right ?

Comment: @Umair it shows more than one items and that's decided on runtime. But even when I am getting more than one items size occupied by list view is only of one item's size. It's scrollable though ( that's fine).

Comment: ok I have posted the answer now your list will show 7-8 items and will be bigger and for the rest of the layout you need to use cardviews intead if you want to get the exact layout as in the screenshot.

Comment: @Naila and let me know if there is still some problem.

Comment: thanks @Umair.. I'll get back in a while :-)

Comment: In that case make the relative layout and the linear layout a child of relative layout which in turn will be the child of scrollview, since scrollview can have only one direct child.

Comment: @Naila glad I could be of any help. Please accept and upvote my answer if it helped you. thanks and happy coding :)

Comment: @Umair done :-) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is that you are using 2 layouts in your `scrollview` so the `listview` won't take the scroll of itself and it will limit the list height as well. To go around this you need to pass fix value to your `listview` then it will show completely within that specified height. And the rest of the layout if you want to get exactly as you have shown in the picture you need to use cardview instead.

```
  <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/basic_details"
                    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/list_item_bg">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_member_details_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_40sdp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_40sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                        android:text="@string/member_details"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="16dp" />

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/lv_members"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="500dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_member_details_label"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_40sdp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_40sdp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_40sdp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:divider="@color/colorLightGrey"
                        android:dividerHeight="@dimen/_1sdp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
```